# Reading and comparing multiple XML nodes from web in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need a little help. I have an XML file in a web and I call that file with:

```
 String URLString = "http://myweb.tld/myfile.xml";
 var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
 xmlDocument.Load(URLString);
```

And reader works, no errors.

Now I want to read some tags in the XML, so I use:

```
XmlNodeList xnCheck = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/blab/bla");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnCheck)
if ((Text1.Text == xn["Name"].InnerText) & (Text2.Text == xn["Pwd"].InnerText))
{
  status.Text = "Correct";
}
else status.Text = "Wrong data";
break;
}
```

When I try read, I always get "wrong data" and i don't understand why.

This is XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<blap>

<bla>
<Name>name1</Name>
<Pwd>12345678</Pwd>
</bla>

<bla>
<Name>name2</Name>
<Pwd>87654321</Pwd>
</bla>

</blap>
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the IF to be

```
if ((Text1.Text == xn["Name"].InnerText) && (Text2.Text == xn["Pwd"].InnerText))
{
  status.Text = "Correct";
}
```

That is two &'s not just one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your problem is the & on this line

```
if ((Text1.Text == xn["Name"].InnerText) & (Text2.Text == xn["Pwd"].InnerText))
```

your should be able to solve the problem with:

```
if ((Text1.Text == xn["Name"].InnerText) && (Text2.Text == xn["Pwd"].InnerText))
```

You are also selecting the wrong nodes. The following:

```
.SelectNodes("/blab/bla")
```

should be:

```
.SelectNodes("/blap/bla")
```

And one more thing:

You should break out of the loop once you have found the correct match and you should only update the status one time. Here is how your loop should be rewritten:

```
        string sStatus = "Wrong data";

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnCheck)
        {
            if ((Text1.Text == xn["Name"].InnerText) && (Text2.Text == xn["Pwd"].InnerText))
            {
                sStatus = "Correct";
                break;
            }
        }
        status.Text = sStatus;
```